# Dropdown lists in angular form

Tags: angular, formgroups

I am trying to create 2 dropdown lists in angular.. One should have a key(code) and the other should have a value (Name) of that key. I am able to get all data in dropdown lists but unable to filter on the second dropdown.

Data is returned via http call to an API and returns as below:

```
[
{"code":"GL07LAB","name":"Waitomo Caves"},
{"code":"GL08T","name":"Taupo 2 Day Tour"},
{"code":"GL08TD","name":"Waitomo & Rotorua (Deluxe Accommodation)"},
{"code":"GL08THX","name":" Hobbiton & Taupo 3 Day Tour"}
]
```

Modal.component.ts:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() editTourData;
tourFrom: FormGroup;
public callUpdate : boolean = false;

agents: any = ["1988","1044"];
reservationEngines: any = ["resnet","jrs"];
tours: any = [];


private myclass: MyClass;
 // If I hardcode the data, it works fine
  //tournames: any = '[{"code":"GL07LAB","name":"Waitomo Caves Black Water Rafting Black Labyrinth Day Tour"},{"code":"GL08T","name":"Waitomo & Rotorua & Taupo 2 Day Tour"}]';

//If I subscribe the result from below call, it fails even though the data is in similar format as above hard coded array. 
tournames: any = this.tourService.getTourNameByTourCode().map((r: Response) => r.json);



private map2 = new Map<string, string>()
  private objs = this.tournames
  private obj3 = <Array<MyClass>>this.tournames
  tourcode: string;

  constructor(public toastr:ToastrService,
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    public router: Router,
    public tourService: TouraccessService,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
           }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("this.editTourData :", this.editTourData);
    console.log("subscribed data is", this.tournames)
    console.log("objs is", this.objs)

    if(this.editTourData != undefined && this.editTourData != null && this.editTourData.hasOwnProperty('tour_id')){
      this.tourFrom = this.formBuilder.group({
        reservation_engine: [this.editTourData.reservation_engine , [Validators.required]],
        agent_product_code: [this.editTourData.agent_product_code,[Validators.required]],
        tour_id: [this.editTourData.tour_id, [Validators.required]],
        tour_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        agent_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        agent_id: [this.editTourData.agent_id, [Validators.required]],
        code: ['', [Validators.required]]
      });
      this.callUpdate = true;
    } else {
      console.log("this.editTourData is undefined");
      this.tourFrom = this.formBuilder.group({
        reservation_engine: ['' , [Validators.required]],
        agent_product_code: ['',[Validators.required]],
        tour_id: ['', [Validators.required]],
        tour_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        agent_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        agent_id: ['', [Validators.required]],
        code: ['', [Validators.required]]

      });
    }
    console.log("tournames are", this.tournames)
    console.log("objs are", this.obj3)
    this.getTours();
    this.getAgents();
    this.getTourNameByTourCode();
   }

  get countries(): string[] {
    var arr = []
    this.obj3.forEach(function (value) {
      arr.push(value.code)
    }); 
    return arr;
  }
  get cities(): string[] | undefined {
    var returnArray = []        
    var name = this.obj3.find(e => e.code === this.tourcode)    
    returnArray.push(name.name)
    return returnArray;
  }
```

Modal.component.html:

```
     <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Tour Code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select formControlName="agent_product_code" [(ngModel)]="tourcode">
                        <option *ngFor="let tourcode of countries" [value]="tourcode"> {{ tourcode }} </option>
<!--                    <option *ngFor="let tour of tours" value="{{tour.code}}">{{tour.code}}</option> -->
                  </select> 
                <control-messages [control]="tourFrom.controls.agent_product_code"></control-messages>          
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Tour Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select formControlName="tour_name" *ngIf="tourcode" [(ngModel)]="city" [value]="city">
                            <option *ngFor="let city of cities"> {{ city }} </option>
    <!--                    <option *ngFor="let tour of tours" value="{{tour.code}}">{{tour.code}}</option> -->
                      </select> 
                        <control-messages [control]="tourFrom.controls.tour_name"></control-messages>          
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I recommend using the code formatters, this helps to read the examples better.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Post your code. also are you wanting to show entries in the second dropdown that are similar (starting with) "GL08T" ?

Comment: first dropdown : I should be able to select GL07LAB .. On select, the second drop down should display "Waitomo Caves"

Comment: @GustavoSantamaría  I am trying to created a filtered drop down list here

Comment: @yomateo I have added the codes accordingly in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Catch first dropdown list change event and patch second dropdown.

```
form.controls['formProperty'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  form.patchValue(patchRequest)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Akif, I am new to this.. Do you have sample of change event and patch?

Comment: form.controls['formProperty'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  form.patchValue(patchRequest)
});
Just change 'formProperty' and patchRequest.